# What is the part of speech for 'forecast'

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the part of speech for 'forecast' in the following sentence?
I think it's 'noun', however, my friend said it's a verb.

> Sales at department stores during this back to school season are
> **forecast** to rise 15.7％ from a year earlier.

Comment: In your sentence, "are forecast" is the *present passive* of the verb *to forecast*, which is spelled and pronounced exactly the same as the noun. One might expect the verb form to be "are forecasted," but it's irregular and follows the same pattern as the verb "cast," where the 3 principal parts are all the same.

Answer (score 2):

It is a verb.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forecast#google_vignette) explains and gives a similar example:

> verb [ T ]
> to say what you expect to happen in the future:
> [ + to infinitive ] Oil prices are forecast to increase by less than two percent this year.